# How to get data from POST url ajax

Tags: c#, ajax

Using ajax POST a url http://test/jy/post.php will get some value below

> People,1220,temperature,26C,CO2 concentration,30ppm,3.jpg

Want to put each of them separately into my input text.

Trying to alert data, but it show [object],don't know how to do.

Here is my js:

```
    window.onload = load();

    function load() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://test/jy/post.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope someone can tell me how to do it or hint me , thanks!

Comment: Debug on firefox, put a breakpint in alert and show the structure and content

Comment: try using `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the data in the POST response is JSON.

As mentioned by @Kaushik you can use JSON.stringify(data) to convert the JSON data to a string.

First of all, I would recommend that you take a look at the content at the following link which explains JSON objects and how to work with them. [JSON Objects - W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)

For my examples, I have used https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos to return example JSON data.

If you wish to only access certain properties of the JSON object then you could accomplish this using the following code. Please bear in mind that the following code snippet assumes that the JSON object consists of a single record.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (data) => {
    console.log('User ID: ' + data.userId);
    console.log('Title: ' + data.title);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the JSON data consists of an array of JSON objects then you could approach this with the following code.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (data) => {
    data.forEach((record) => {
      console.log('User ID: ' + record.userId);
      console.log('Title: ' + record.title);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you simply just want to display all JSON data as a string then the following code would accomplish this.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (data) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```